# Find element with order 12 of multiplicative group using CRT

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have been stuck on this question for a long time and don't really understand how the Chinese remainder the is related to the order of a unit.

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find an element of order 12 in G =
(Z/105Z)^×. Are there any elements of larger order in G?

Here G is the multiplicative ring mod 105.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese Remainder theorem, we have that 
$$\bigl(\mathbf Z/105\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}\simeq\bigl(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}\times\bigl(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}\times\bigl(\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z\bigr)^{\!\times}$$
As the order of an element $(x,y,z)$ in the product is the l.c.m. of the orders of $a,b,c$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $a$ is a divisor of $2$, the order of $b$ a divisor of $4$ ands the order of $c$ a divisor of $6$, so it is enough to take $a=1$, $b$ of order $4$, e.g. $b=2$, and $c$ of order $6$, say $c=3$.

We first solve $\; x\equiv 1\mod 3,\quad x\equiv 2\mod 5$.

A Bézout relation between $3$ and $5$ is: $\;2\cdot 3 -5=1$, hence the solutions are
$$x\equiv 2\cdot 6-1\cdot 5=7\mod 15.$$

Now let's solve: $\; x\equiv 7\mod 15,\quad x\equiv 3\mod 7$.

A Bézout relation between $15$ and $7$ is: $\;15-2\cdot 7=1$, hence the solutions are:
$$x\equiv 3\cdot 15-7\cdot14=-53\equiv \color{red}{52}\mod 105.$$

Comment: thanks you so much, thinking of the ctr as an isomorphism was what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Note that $3$ has order $6$ modulo $7$, and $2$ has order $4$ modulo $5$. Solve the simultaneous system of congruences $x\equiv 3\pmod{7}$, $x\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.