# How to find an element of order 30 in the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_{900}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to find at least one element which has order $30$ in the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_{900}$. I'm following [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1480593) but not really understood how to apply correctly the CRT to set the three congruences. In particular, I don't understand why the order of a is a divisor of 2 etc. Can anyone explain me better how to apply the CRT to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n\ge2$, $1+n$ has multiplicative order $n$ modulo $n^2$.
Just observe that
$$(1+n)^k\equiv 1+kn\pmod{n^2}.$$

Comment: I need to use the CRT...

Answer (score 0):

We have $$900=2^2\times 3^2\times 5^2$$

If $\gcd(n,900)=1$ then the order of $n\pmod {900}$ is the lcm of its orders $\pmod {2^2,3^2,5^2}$.

We start $n\equiv 2 \pmod {25}$.  Direct computation shows that this has order $20$, so $4$ has order $10\pmod {25}$.

Now, $4$ has order $3\mod 9$, and let's just take $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Then we just need to solve $$n\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \quad \& \quad n\equiv 4\pmod {225}$$

Easy to see that $\boxed {n\equiv 229 \pmod {900}}$ works.

Another approach is simple trial and error.  That method quickly gets us to $n=11$ as a smaller solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I haven't understood. How can you find 20? What is the logical consequence to say that 4 has order 10? then you say 4 has order 3mod9... That's exactly the same reasoning of the answer found that I haven't understood.

Comment: The numbers involved are very small.  It's easy to simply compute.

Comment: For instance, with $4\pmod 9$, we easily see that $4^2\equiv 7$ and $4^3\equiv 28\equiv 1$.

Comment: To be clear:  I started with $2$ randomly.  It's the smallest candidate, so why not?  You could have started with $3\pmod {25}$ instead.  I suggest you do that!  It will lead you to a new element of order $30\pmod {900}$ and it's good practice.

Comment: So, basically, we need to find a common element? You found 4 in $Z_{25}$ and $\Bbb Z_{9}$... Why do I need to set the two congruences? Why didn't you apply the same reasoning to $Z_{4}$? What is the correlation between this reasoning with order 30 of a certain element I need to find? You have found "random" elements that have a certain order in each $Z_{n}$... Sadly, it's not really clear. It isn't a problem of computation but I want to understand clearly the logical order of the steps of your reasoning.

Comment: You need three congruences $a\pmod 4, b\pmod 9, c\pmod {25}$ such that the lcm of the orders is $30$.  I started with $25$ because I thought I could come fairly close and I did!  I hit an element of order $20$ straight off.  Squaring that element gave me an element of order $10$.  Now all I need is the $3$.  I tried the same element $\pmod 9$ and, luckily, found that it had order $3$.  That saved me some time.  It meant I could let $b=c$, and immediately work $\pmod {9\times 25}$.  Not real important though, it just saved a step.  Anyway, having the $10$ and the $3$ I was done.

Comment: I think you are hoping for something that really isn't there.  In general, it's hard to find elements of some desired order.  Here, the numbers are so small that anything you try will work.  There are a few useful patterns (such as the one identified by @LordSharktheUnknown) but, really, it's generally a matter of playing with some calculations.

Comment: Worth noting:  in this case I certainly wouldn't use simultaneous congruences.  Much faster to just try numbers.  Since you need classes prime to $900$,  the smallest example is $7$.  That has order $12\pmod {900}$....not much help.  Second try is $11$ which works!  Done.  Again...with very small numbers, like these, just about anything you try will work (with a bit of flexibility).

Comment: With reference to the first of the three comments, in practice, you have used the congruence $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ because you have already "obtained" the lcm with the order 10 and 3. And you "combined" the two congruences mod25 and mod9 simply because you have found 4 as a common element. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  To be sure:  I didn't need to find a "common element" as you put it, but having stumbled on one I was glad to skip the extra step.  As I say, I suggest you start with $3\pmod {25}$ and build up a solution from there.  Just for practice.